# Postgresql not starting

Tags: postgresql

```
i have restarted my local ubuntu 18.4 server and postgresql 10 is not running now kindly help

trying start by : `sudo systemctl start postgresql@10-main`
Receiving  following errors.

    Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...

    Error:   start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.
    Can't exec "": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 211.

    Error: could not exec   start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/post

    postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No 

    postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
    Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.


`apt-cache show postgresql`:

    Package: postgresql
    Architecture: all
    Version: 10+190
    Priority: optional
    Section: database
    Source: postgresql-common (190)
    Origin: Ubuntu
    Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
    Original-Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <pkg-postgresql-public@lists.alioth.debian.org>
    Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
    Installed-Size: 62
    Depends: postgresql-10
    Suggests: postgresql-doc
    Filename: pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql_10+190_all.deb
    Size: 5784
    MD5sum: 2fb6f13d95e354c47a1df602f68f7131
    SHA1: 45e8e55044259941faba82282243f11194baf66c
    SHA256: 02baa3ea401deb634a4307a8d0e25378613ffbf3b3ddbda9cc03d5277a5ea7a4
    Description-en: object-relational SQL database (supported version)
     This metapackage always depends on the currently supported PostgreSQL
     database server version.
////////// systemctl restart postgresql.service  /////////////////

~$ systemctl restart postgresql.service
~$ systemctl status  postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-09-25 11:03:27 PKT; 19s ago
  Process: 7038 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7038 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
 Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running? how did you install postgres? Also why are you starting `postgresql@10-main`? and not just `postgresql.service`?

Comment: I'd guess your problem is at `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 211.`, possibly due to a configuration error.

Comment: @j-money    ubuntu version is 18.04 it was already installed i have no idea tried postgresql.service command not found

Comment: `systemctl restart postgresql.service`. I don't know if ubuntu ships with postgres, but I've been wrong before, edit your original post with the output of `apt-cache show postgresql`

Comment: @j-money  please check

Comment: Please read the markdown editing help section of your post, I do not want to keep editing your post for formatting issues. There should be a question mark in the top right of the editing box. What happened when you tried `systemctl restart postgresql.service`?

Comment: @j-money  original question edited

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do with postgres, it might be useful to update your question with the entire background, What do you want to do? What you have tried? What guides (if any) have you followed?

I am not sure why you are trying to start `postgres@10-main` nor am I confident I know what that is. But it should be sufficient to simply run

#### To start the service:

```
systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

#### To start the service on every boot

```
systemctl reenable postgresql.service
```

Based off your most recent post update, postgres has started and is up and running.

Comment: your right but when i am trying to access my service through url this error comes up.

Comment: Failed to establish database connection:SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: Please read the first part of my quesiton again, also please read up on how to format quesitons, answers, and comments https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting